# Checkbox is showing two

Tags: css, checkbox

I applied custom css on my checkbox but now it is showing two..
When I just apply the custom css to the previous one it doesn't apply them.
Can anyone help fixing it?

```css
.treejs-checkbox {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #00EA90;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #00EA90 inset;
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0.72, 1.07);
}
```

```html
<li>
  <span class="treejs-checkbox"></span>
  <span class="treejs-label">Teams</span>
</li>
```

It just shows double checkboxes.
[image: It shows like this]

Answer (score 0):

There was already existing CSS and I inspected and just changed the existing ones.

```
.treejs .treejs-checkbox::before {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 2px solid #00EA90;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #00EA90 inset;
        transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0.72, 1.07);
}
```

I used psuedo to change them. :)